# add component using * syntax

Tags: java, swing

I have working piece of code that adds a scroll bar  to JPanel in the following form

```
add(scrollPane,"*");
```

I usually would use

```
add(scrollPane);
```

Seemingly the former and the later syntax vary in the way they layout the scroll bar inside the JPanel . I can see the differences but anyone know a formal reason for it ?

What does the * mean here ?

Comment: My "gut" feeling is either you are using a custom layout manager or the person who wrote the original code didn't understand what they were doing...

Comment: @MadProgrammer well he is no longer here so cant really say what he was thinking . But yeah i do find this syntax a bit awkward and I didnt come across this before . Thanks for the pointers though .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`Container#add(Component, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)).

The particular meaning will depend on the layout manager been used and could be ignored completely if the layout manager does not support constraints.

Consider `GridBagLayout` for example, in order to add components (with any real control/meaning), you would need to pass it a reference to a `GridBagConstraints`.  `BorderLayout` is the same.